# Python list of lists to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this sample code below that turns a Python list of lists into a pandas DataFrame, but I need to DataFrame orientation to be inversed, any idea how to achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

i = np.zeros(10)
i.fill(40)

j = np.zeros(10)
j.fill(60)

df = pd.DataFrame([i, j])

display(df)
```

The output of this is a structure like this:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 | 40 |
| 1 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 |

But, what I want is to get a structure like this, how can I turn a list of lists into such format?

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |
| 40 | 60 |

Comment: How about : `df.T`

Answer (score 2):

just transpose the dataframe :

```
df = df.T
```

or prepare your df the way you want at the first place:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: i, 1: j})
```

output:

```
>>
      0     1
0  40.0  60.0
1  40.0  60.0
2  40.0  60.0
3  40.0  60.0
4  40.0  60.0
5  40.0  60.0
6  40.0  60.0
7  40.0  60.0
8  40.0  60.0
9  40.0  60.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest trying

```
df.transpose()
```

for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to create a two columns dataframe directly

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(i, j))
# or specify the column header
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(i, j), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

```
print(df)

      0     1
0  40.0  60.0
1  40.0  60.0
2  40.0  60.0
3  40.0  60.0
4  40.0  60.0
5  40.0  60.0
6  40.0  60.0
7  40.0  60.0
8  40.0  60.0
9  40.0  60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to correct this before creating your dataframe, you can use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and then create the dataframe.

```
inp_arr = np.column_stack((i,j))
df = pd.DataFrame(inp_arr)
```